# REGEX to extract words between the first pipe symbol

Tags: text-parsing

```
 --- blablabla N° : 0533333333 | XXXXX XXXX XXX  | 24/12/2016 | - blabla  ,
```

this is my line of log and i want to match the XXXXX XXXX XXX
I did this regex

```
(?<=\|)[^|]++(?=\|)
```

to match all things between the first pipe symbol.
but the result is the words between the first pipe symbol and the words between the second pipe symbol
how can i get only the words between the first pipe symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
^.*?\|(.*?)\|.*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^.*?\|    consume everything up until the first pipe
(.*?)|    match and consume everything between the first and second pipes
.*$       consume the remainder of the line
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: this regex match all sentence

Comment: I did this Regex (?<=\|)[A-Za-zA-zÀ-ú \/\w+0-9._%+-]+(?=\|)    It capture everything between pipes but i cant just the words between the first couple of pipes how can i do that?

Comment: I have answered your question as far as I know.  What about my regex doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: (?<=\|)[A-Za-zA-zÀ-ú \/\w+0-9._%+-]+\s\s+(?=\|)    this  regex work it capture only the words between the first couple of pipes

Comment: Isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: yes the last one that i did works  thank's for u're replay